# Why are changes to my settings file not getting picked up after compilation

Tags: app-config

In VB.net, I have created a settings file for my OCX which is accessed via My.Settings. The settings file contains a list of values which is used to populate a combo box at runtime. The list might change over time so an admin should be able to modify the settings file as they need to. I have compiled the DLL and registered it successfully. The list populates as expected, however when I add one item to the list in the settings file, it is not picked up at runtime. The original list remains. I can't figure out why this is. The only way I can update the list is to do it in Visual Studio Project->Properties->Settings and then recompile the DLL.

I have tried changing the compilation configuration from Debug to Release, I've looked extensively online and changed the Access Modifier to Public from Friend. Makes no difference

```
For Each entry As String In My.Settings.Depts
                cboDept.Items.Add(entry)
 Next
 cboDept.SelectedIndex = 0 'select first item in dropdown list
```

Here is an excerpt of my settings file:

```
<applicationSettings>
      <My.MySettings>
        <setting name="Depts" serializeAs="Xml">
          <value>
            <ArrayOfString xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
              xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
              <string>DeptA</string>
              <string>DeptB</string>
              <string>DeptC</string>
              <string>DeptD</string>
            </ArrayOfString>
          </value>
        </setting>
    </My.MySettings>
</applicationSettings>
```

The settings file contains a list of Departments which populate a dropdown list but adding a new one manually does not cause it to be added to the dropdown list at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved - I discovered that the Root Namespace in Visual Studio -> Project Properties was blank. Putting the correct value there makes the application work as it should.
Thanks for your time!